# understanding javascript code with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat

Below you see a part of the server-side code of the [twich.me](https://github.com/isaacsu/twich) node.js chat:

```
exports.channel = function(MESSAGE_BACKLOG, MESSAGE_TRUNCATE) {
    return (function() {
        var messages  = [],
            callbacks = [];

        return {
            appendMessage : function (nick, room, type, text) {

  //truncate message if necessary
  if (type == 'msg' && text.length > MESSAGE_TRUNCATE) {
   text = text.substr(0, MESSAGE_TRUNCATE) + "... (trunc.)";
  }

  //message
  var m = {
   nick: nick,
   type: type, // "msg", "join", "part"
   text: text,
   room: room,
   timestamp: (new Date()).getTime()
  };

  //output to console
//  mlog(m);

  //push msg on message stack
  messages.push( m );

  //???
                while (callbacks.length > 0) {
                    callbacks.shift().callback([m]);
                }

  //old messages get pushed out of message stack
                while (messages.length > MESSAGE_BACKLOG) {
                    messages.shift();
                }
            },

            query : function (room, since, callback) {
                var matching = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    var message = messages[i];
                    if (message.timestamp > since && room == message.room) {
                        matching.push(message)
                    }
                }

    //???
                if (matching.length != 0) {
                    callback(matching);
                }
                else {
                    callbacks.push({ timestamp: new Date(), callback: callback });
                }
            },

     //run initially when script starts
            init : function() {
                // clear old callbacks older than 25 seconds (lowered from 30 seconds to get round rmit proxy server's 30sec timeout
                setInterval(function () {
                    var now = new Date();
                    while (callbacks.length > 0 && now - callbacks[0].timestamp > 25*1000) {
                        callbacks.shift().callback([]);
                    }
                }, 3000);
                return "hi";
            }
        }
    }());
}
```

The code is responsible for storing and retrieving chat messages from one of the chat rooms.
I am not a javascript programmer. My background is with PHP where everything is procedural. I want to solve this with memcached instead. But first I need to understand what exactly is going on. I have added extra comments. What I don't understand is all the stuff with the callbacks. Could you help me understand what the callbacks are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want but here's what going on:

```
            while (callbacks.length > 0) {
                callbacks.shift().callback([m]);
            }
```

while the amount of objects in the array callbacks is greater than 0,
callbacks.shift() function will apparently return an object with a property called callback which is a function. and it's calling that function with an array that has the variable m in it.

```
            if (matching.length != 0) {
                callback(matching);
            }
            else {
                callbacks.push({ timestamp: new Date(), callback: callback });
            }
        }
```

if the amount of objects in the array matching is not 0, call the function callback or if it does, cal the function callback.push with an object.